# GWT: FlexTable vs Table

Tags: gwt

Under what circumstance I should use FlexTable instead of HTMLTable?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

HTMLTable is an abstract class. FlexTable extends this class as well as Grid. HTMLTable is thus never used directly, but you would use FlexTable or Grid. The question is than probably when to use FlexTable? and when to use Grid?

The difference between those classes is that a Grid always has the same number of rows and/or columns while a FlexTable can have different rows per column and different columns per row (This is made possible due to the html properties rowspan and colspan).

Thus when you need flexibale rows or columns you can use FlexTable and otherwise Grid.

However, **FlexTable is extremely slow in Internet Explorer**, due to slow DOM methods that are used to create a the table. Therefore, avoid FlexTable if you can or only use it create a simple layout (although in that case the DockPanel might be somewhat easier to use).

Comment: But then again, everything is extremely slow in Internet Explorer :)

Comment: FWIW I tried the performance test mentioned here http://whatwouldnickdo.com/wordpress/401/performance-grid-vs-flextable/  (the actual test is here: http://whatwouldnickdo.com/gridvflex/GridVFlex.html)

On Windows 7 - IE 11, Firefox 28 and Chrome 34.   There were only small differences in performance, with FlexTable usually being faster than 'Grid'.  Chrome beat FF and IE by a factor of 2 most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare like that.

As per Docs

```
HTMLTable contains the common table algorithms for Grid and FlexTable.
```

So Grid or `Flextable` extends `HTMLTable`.

And

A `Flexible table` that creates cells on demand. It can be jagged (that is, each row can contain a different number of cells) and individual cells can be set to span multiple rows or columns.

Now  we can have a question `Grid or Flextable` ???

Here is the [Performance difference between grid and Flextable.](http://whatwouldnickdo.com/wordpress/401/performance-grid-vs-flextable/)