# how to relate a flextable row with a database row in gwt

Tags: gwt, row, flextable

i'm creating a simple project to try gwt, but i'm a real noob :)
i've a table in my db, each row in this table has a unique id.
i want my application to read this table and display it's contents in a flextable, omitting the column containing the unique id in the db, 'cause the user is not interested in that id.
after that, i want the user to click on a row of the flextable and get a detailed view... but i need my unique id to get the detailed data about that row in my db!
i'm able to determine in which cell of the flextable the user clicked, so i created a simple widget with a string property and an int property, and i add this widget to the flextable setting the string property to the text from the db i want to display in the flextable and the int property with the db id value... when the user clicks, i get the widget contained in the cell and i can get my id back... but it looks like a very complex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom widget is the way to go as soon as your requirements exceed the functionality of the standard widgets provided by GWT.

Note: you may want to reconsider and use Grid instead of FlexTable. Grid seems better in your case since each row contains the same number of cells. See related topic about [Grid and FlexTable comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765638/gwt-flextable-vs-table).